# Error while trying to configure samba domain controller With LDAP on CentOS 5.4

Tags: ldap, centos, samba, openldap, centos5

I am getting an error as mentioned below while trying to configure samba over ldap on Centos 5.4.

Error looking for next uid in sambaDomainName=sambaDomain,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com:invalid DN at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/smbldap_tools.pm line 1071.

I have tried editing the /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf and Replace SID="%your_sid%" and userSmbHome="%samba_netbios_name%" but it did not work.

Comment: Do the objects in LDAP exist, that it is trying to reference?  I.e. sambaDomainName=sambaDomain,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com  Is that really the DN (I assume you protected the innocent and hid any private names in that DN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked over the whole thing again and enabled Samba using Swat but it worked fine over that.

I refered the below mentioned URL:

Ch10:_Windows,_Linux,_and_Samba">http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch10*:_Windows,_Linux,_and_Samba